# Como deixar uma unica versão do Python no Linux/Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, bash

[image: Multiplas Versões do Python 3]

Eu até entendo o fato de haver o Python2.7, o que por si só já é bem chato porque toda hora baixo os módulos pra o lugar errado, mas quando tentei atualizar a versão 3.6 para 3.7 acabou instalando mais uma. Como resolver?

Comment: É indicado que você pare de instalar apenas com `pip install` e passe a utilizar `python3.6 -m pip install`, pois desta maneira você tem explico a versão utilizada. Melhor que isso é se você criar o costume de criar ambientes virtuais.

Comment: E não tente desinstalar a versão 2 do seu sistema, isso poderá quebrar muitas dependências internas do próprio sistema operacional

Comment: Não tem como, porque tem inúmeros outros softwares que usam Python 2 e Python 3, infelizmente estamos condenados todos a manter as 2 na máquina pelo futuro previsível.

Comment: Só se usar Ubuntu (e semelhantes). As distribuições rolling release já vem somente com o Python 3.7

Comment: ... ou `pip3 install  ...`

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR:

Você não precisa se preocupar com isso - que versões do Python estão instaladas para uso interno do sistema (no caso o Ubuntu) são um problema dele. Para trabalhar com Python você deve aprender a gerenciar ambientes isolados (virtualenv), e instalar localmente a versão do Python e as bibliotecas na versão desejada.

## Resposta original

Na verdade, não é interessante deixar uma única versão do Python - você está perguntando uma coisa para o problema errado.

O que você precisa saber é *como* lidar com múltiplas versões do Python na mesma máquina.

O sistema operacional *naturalmente* vai instalar mais de uma versão do Python - mesmo que os pacotes principais do sistema já estejam usando Python 3, e o sistema possa ter somente um Python 3.7, basta algum software que precise do Python 2 como requisito ser instalado (por exemplo, o GIMP 2.10), e o Python 2.10 vai ser instalado também.

O que você precisa aprender é isolar *todos* os seus projetos de Python usando "virtualenvs" - [tente começar por este artigo](http://blog.aprendapython.com.br/articles/entendendo-virtualenv-1fr69/).

Resumidamente, um virtualenv, ou uma tecnologia semelhante, como "pipenv" ou "buildout", permitem que você crie um ambiente isolado em uma pasta, onde você vai ter uma versão pré-selecionada do Python, e vai instalar todos os módulos que você precisa para um dado projeto naquela pasta. Esses módulos do Python não são vistos pelo sistema operacional, e funcionam de forma independente. As bibliotecas e pacotes terceiros são instaladas no virtualenv com o comando `pip` (e nunca com o gerenciador de pacotes do sistema, como o `apt` ou `dnf`/`yum`)

Isso resolve um monte, uma quantidade quase infinita, de problemas. Por exemplo, é comum projetos para Web de Python precisarem de dezenas de dependencias externas - bastaria que uma dessas dependencias tivesse uma versão diferente do pacote do que está disponível como pacote do seu sistema, e você não teria como desenvolver o sistema no seu computador. (Atualizar manualmente um pacote instalado pelo gerenciador do sistema é garantir que você está corrompendo seu sistema operacional e vai precisar reformatar em breve).

Então, por exemplo, vamos supor que eu estou num Ubuntu 18.04  e instalo algum aplicativo, empacotado para o Ubuntu, que use o Django como base. O aplicativo usa o django 1.2 - uma versão antiga. O "apt" vai se encarregar de instalar no Python do sistema essa versão do Django.

Aí eu resolvo iniciar um sistema novo, em Django - quero usar a versão mais recente - a 2.2 - eu não vou tentar brigar e forçar o django 2.2 dentro das pastas de /usr/lib/python .... só pra começar, isso destruiria o aplicativo que eu instalei com APT que usa o django 1.2.

Eu vou na minha pasta do usuário criar um  "virtualenv", com a versão do Python que eu quero, e instalar o django e os pacotes desejados ali - em geral entram versões mais recentes do que as disponiveis pelo sistema operacional.

A sequência de comandos é (no Linux):

```
python3.7 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install django
```

No windows:

```
python3.7 -m venv env
env/Scripts/activate.bat
pip install django
```

A primeira linha cria o ambiente isolado, em uma pasta com o nome "env" - essa pasta contem um executável do Python e um diretório de lib. A segunda linha "ativa" o virtualenv - em todo shell (cmd, no Windows), em que você for trabalhar com o projeto, tem que executar os comandos do arquivo `activate`. Isso coloca o nome do virtualenv entre parentes no começo do prompt - vai aparecer algo como `(env) /home/epx/$` - indicando que o virtualenv está ativo.

E a terceira linha é tudo o que é necessário para instalar a versão mais recente do Django, independente do django que esteja disponível para seu sistema, e independente de outros projetos no mesmo computador.
E mais ainda: com isso é possível reproduzir a instalação dos seus projetos com exatametne as mesmas versões de pacotes do Python em qualquer computador - então é possível desenvolver seu projeto num Ubuntu 19.04, e colocar o mesmo pra rodar em um servidor CentOS de 2017 - há uma série de coisas para aprender sobre o virtualenv e setup de projetos em Python, mas a base é essa.